# Are the (Bezout) coefficients for $\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = q\sigma(n^2) - 2(q - 1)n^2$ (where $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number) unique?

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

In what follows, denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$, the *deficiency* of $x$ by $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$, and the *aliquot sum* of $x$ by $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$.

Let $m = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Using the fundamental equation
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)=\sigma(q^k n^2)=\sigma(m)=2m=2q^k n^2$$
and using the fact that $q^k$ and $\sigma(q^k)$ are *relatively prime* (that is, $\gcd(q^k,\sigma(q^k))=1$), then we get that $q^k \mid \sigma(n^2)$, whereupon we obtain
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}.$$

Now, using the identity
$$\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}=\frac{A-C}{B-D},$$
which works whenever $B \neq 0$, $D \neq 0$ and $B \neq D$, we obtain
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}=\frac{(q - 1)(2n^2 - \sigma(n^2))}{q^k - 1}$$
whereupon we get, by another application of the identity above, that
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}=\frac{(q - 1)(2n^2 - \sigma(n^2))}{q^k - 1}=\frac{\sigma(n^2) - (q - 1)(2n^2 - \sigma(n^2))}{q^k - (q^k - 1)},$$
from which we finally obtain
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=q\sigma(n^2) - 2(q-1)n^2.$$

---

However, [Dris (Lemma 2.1, pages 13 to 14)](https://nntdm.net/volume-23-2017/number-2/12-20/) proved in the year $2017$ that, in fact, we have
$$\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}.$$

This means that
$$\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=q\sigma(n^2) - 2(q-1)n^2, \tag{1}$$
where we note that $\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)) \geq 3$.

Note that Equation **(1)** is an instance of [Bezout's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Now the hyperlinked Wikipedia page for Bezout's Identity says that the Bezout coefficients
$$y = -2(q - 1)$$
and
$$z = q$$
(obtained from $\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=yn^2 + z\sigma(n^2)$) are **not unique**.

---

Here then is my:

> **QUESTION:** Can you find another pair of Bezout coefficients $(y',z')$ such that
> $$\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=y' n^2 + z' \sigma(n^2)$$
> holds, where $y' \neq y$ and $z' \neq z$ are **integers**?

Comment: Let $m = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.  Descartes, Frenicle, and subsequently Sorli conjectured that $k=1$ always holds.  If true, then this conjecture would imply that
$$\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)) = D(n^2) = 2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)$$
so that $y' = 2$ and $z' = -1$.

Comment: So I guess the whole point of this question is whether it would be possible to obtain another set of (Bezout) coefficients $(y',z')$ such that
$$\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=y' n^2 + z' \sigma(n^2)$$
holds, where $y' \neq y$ and $z' \neq z$ are **integers**, which is *unconditional*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is nothing specific to your numbers as far as Bezout's identity is concerned.
If the equation $ax+by=\gcd(a,b)$ has a solution $(x_0,y_0)$, then all the infinitely many integer solutions to the equation are given by $x=rt+x_0,y=st+y_0$, where $r=b/\gcd(a,b)$ and $s=-a/\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Aravind!  What is $k$ in your answer?  Is it the same as the $k$ in my question?

Comment: Got it, @Aravind!  An upvote for now.

Comment: Using $t$ instead of the variable $k$ in your (now-edited) answer (I hope you do not mind!), I am getting
$$\gcd\bigl(n^2, \sigma(n^2)\bigr) = n^2 \bigl(q^k t - 2(q - 1)\bigr) + \sigma(n^2) \bigl(-(\sigma(q^k)/2)\cdot t + q\bigr),$$
which does hold.

Comment: I have hereby accepted your answer, @Aravind!  (I will award the bounty to you after an hour or so, as the system does not currently permit me to do so.)

Comment: In your answer, is $t$ (previously $k$) necessarily an integer?  Please advise.  Thank you!

Comment: Yes, $t$ is an integer. Thanks for the bounty.

Comment: Just one last question, @Aravind. Do you have a reference (from a textbook, I presume) for this answer?  I would like to cite said reference, if there is one, in a preprint on odd perfect numbers that I am about to write.  Thank you!

Comment: A Course in Number Theory by H.E. Rose, Chapter 1 states the result explicitly.