# Proof-verification request: On the equation $\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)) = D(n^2)/s(q^k)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm, conjectures, perfect-numbers

(**Preamble:** This question is an offshoot of this [earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4506498).)

In what follows, denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$, the *deficiency* of $x$ by $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$, and the *aliquot sum* of $x$ by $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$.

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.  Descartes, Frenicle, and subsequently Sorli conjectured that $k=1$ always holds.  (In this **proof-verification** request, we shall attempt to prove this conjecture.)

Using the fundamental equation
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)=\sigma(q^k n^2)=\sigma(N)=2N=2q^k n^2$$
and using the fact that $q^k$ and $\sigma(q^k)$ are *relatively prime* (that is, $\gcd(q^k,\sigma(q^k))=1$), then we get that $q^k \mid \sigma(n^2)$, whereupon we obtain that
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}$$
is an odd integer.

From the hyperlinked MSE question above, we have obtained the **identities**
$$\gcd\bigl(n^2,\sigma(n^2)\bigr)=\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}=\frac{2s(n^2)}{D(q^k)}.$$

Now, in a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4506498/are-the-bezout-coefficients-for-gcdn2-sigman2-q-sigman2-2q#comment9464753_4508176) underneath [MSE user Aravind](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/4959)'s answer to the hyperlinked MSE question above, we derived that
$$\gcd\bigl(n^2,\sigma(n^2)\bigr)=n^2 \bigl(q^k t - 2(q - 1)\bigr) + \sigma(n^2) \bigl( - (\sigma(q^k)/2)\cdot t + q \bigr), \tag{1}$$
where $t$ is necessarily an **integer** to be determined by using the identity
$$\gcd\bigl(n^2,\sigma(n^2)\bigr)=\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}. \tag{2}$$

Equating **(1)** and **(2)**, we obtain
$$\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}=n^2 \bigl(q^k t - 2(q - 1)\bigr) + \sigma(n^2) \bigl( - (\sigma(q^k)/2)\cdot t + q \bigr). \tag{3}$$
Multiplying both sides of **(3)** by $s(q^k)$, we obtain
$$2n^2 - \sigma(n^2) = D(n^2) = n^2 \bigl(q^k s(q^k) t - 2(q - 1)s(q^k)\bigr) + \sigma(n^2) \bigl( - (\sigma(q^k)/2) s(q^k) \cdot t + q s(q^k) \bigr). \tag{4}$$

Equating coefficients for $n^2$ and $\sigma(n^2)$ in **(4)**, we have that
$$\begin{cases}
2  = q^k s(q^k) t - 2(q - 1)s(q^k) \\
-1 = - (\sigma(q^k)/2) s(q^k) \cdot t + q s(q^k) 
\end{cases} \tag{5}
$$

The system in **(5)** is a set of two simultaneous "linear" equations in $t$, of the form
$$\begin{cases}
A t + B = 2 \\
C t + D = -1   
\end{cases} \tag{6}
$$
where
$$A = q^k s(q^k), B = - 2(q - 1)s(q^k)$$
and
$$C = - (\sigma(q^k)/2) s(q^k), D = q s(q^k).$$

We now solve the system **(6)** for $t$.  We thereby get
$$\begin{cases}
2D = ADt + BD \\
B = -BCt - BD
\end{cases} \tag{7}
$$
Adding the two equations in **(7)**, we obtain
$$2D + B = (AD - BC)t$$
$$t = \frac{2D + B}{AD - BC}.$$

But
$$2D + B = 2qs(q^k) - 2(q - 1)s(q^k) = s(q^k)\bigl(2q - 2(q - 1)\bigr) = 2s(q^k) \tag{8}$$
and
$$AD - BC = q^{k+1} \bigl(s(q^k)\bigr)^2 - (q - 1)\sigma(q^k) \bigl(s(q^k)\bigr)^2 = \bigl(s(q^k)\bigr)^2 \bigl(q^{k+1} - (q - 1)\sigma(q^k)\bigr) $$
$$= \bigl(s(q^k)\bigr)^2 \bigl(q^{k+1} - (q^{k+1} - 1)\bigr) = \bigl(s(q^k)\bigr)^2. \tag{9}$$

Consequently, from **(8)** and **(9)**, the variable $t$ (which is necessarily an integer) must have the value
$$t = \frac{2D + B}{AD - BC} = \frac{2s(q^k)}{\bigl(s(q^k)\bigr)^2} = \frac{2}{s(q^k)}.$$

Since $s(q^k) \geq 1$ holds in general, then $t$ is an integer implies that either $s(q^k) = 1$ or $s(q^k) = 2$.

> **Want to show:** $s(q^k) = 1$
> Assume to the contrary that $s(q^k) = 2$. This is equivalent to
> $$q^k - 1 = 2(q - 1)$$
> $$q^k - 2q = -1$$
> $$2q - q^k = 1$$
> $$q\bigl(2 - q^{k-1}\bigr) = 1$$
> This implies that $q = 1$ **AND** $2 - q^{k - 1} = 1$, from which we obtain $1 = q^{k - 1}$ and $q = 1$.  The first equation implies that $k = 1$, while the second condition contradicts $q$ being the special prime satisfying $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ (so that $q \geq 5$).

> > Hence, necessarily we have $s(q^k) = 1$, or $k = 1$.

Here is my question:

> Is the method of equating coefficients for $n^2$ and $\sigma(n^2)$ in **(5)** a valid approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simpler algebra, let

$$u = q^k s(q^k) t - 2(q - 1)s(q^k), \; \; v = -(\sigma(q^k)/2)s(q^k) \cdot t + q s(q^k) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

then your $(4)$ becomes

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
2n^2 - \sigma(n^2) & = u \cdot n^2 + v \cdot \sigma(n^2) \\
(2 - u)n^2 & = (1 + v)\sigma(n^2)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

From your $(2)$, we have

$$\gcd\bigl(n^2,\sigma(n^2)\bigr)=\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)} = d \; \; \to \; \; \gcd\left(\frac{n^2}{d},\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{d}\right) = 1 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Dividing both sides of \eqref{eq2A} by $d$ gives

$$(2 - u)\left(\frac{n^2}{d}\right) = (1 + v)\left(\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{d}\right) \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Due to the right side $\gcd$ condition in \eqref{eq3A}, we next have

$$\frac{n^2}{d} \mid (1 + v) \; \; \to \; \; 1 + v = m\left(\frac{n^2}{d}\right) \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

for some integer $m$. Substituting this into \eqref{eq4A} and dividing both sides by $\frac{n^2}{d}$ gives

$$2 - u = m\left(\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{d}\right) \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Regarding your question of

> Is the method of equating coefficients for $n^2$ and $\sigma(n^2)$ in **(5)** a valid approach?

This is equivalent to having $m = 0$ in \eqref{eq5A} and \eqref{eq6A}. However, it seems you just stated this, without providing anything in your derivation that requires this to be the case. Thus, unless I'm missing something (if so, please indicate what that is), I believe you haven't provided sufficient proof to show that restriction (i.e., your method of equating coefficients) is valid, which means that $m$ can possibly be some non-zero integer instead.

Comment: I seem to have proved that the assumption $m \neq 0$ leads to the same desired conclusion, $k  = 1$.  Please do check out my recently composed answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4510047/28816), @JohnOmielan.

Comment: @JOSEARNALDOBEBITADRIS Thank you for the notice. However, I don't have time now to check on your new answer. Also, since it seems your answer here doesn't directly address your question, I suggest that it's more appropriate to instead post a new question, linking to this one, as you've done previously (e.g., linking your current question to a previous one). This will help to give other members a chance to see & read your solution, so they can possibly give you feedback, not only possibly in comments, but also with more details in answers to your new question.

Comment: My attempt failed, @JohnOmielan.  Nonetheless, I invite you to check out the details to see what you could salvage from the "proof".

Comment: Okay, will do so, @JohnOmielan.

Comment: I have conclusively shown that $m = 0$ must hold, @JohnOmielan.  Please check out this [new MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4510135) and the [answer contained therein](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4510197/28816).

Comment: @JOSEARNALDOBEBITADRIS You've spent a lot of time & effort on this, so I hope you're successful, or at least have made good progress. I've looked through your new question & answer, but didn't offhand see anything incorrect. Perhaps someone else will carefully go through those posts (and maybe even your previous supporting posts & comments) to try to confirm there are no mistakes and, if they find any, then help you to fix them if they can be relatively easily handled.

Comment: Thank you for skimming through the proof, and for the kind words!  I will try to get some more sleep, as it is only around 5:25 AM here in the Philippines.  I will typeset a preprint and upload it to arXiv after a few days.

Comment: I am (at least) getting
$$\gcd(1+v,2-u)=m=2-ts(q^k),$$
whence I then do not know how to derive $m=0$, @JohnOmielan.

Comment: @ARNIEBEBITA-DRIS Note your specific question here was *just* whether or not your method was valid, so my answer stated that you were *implicitly* using that $m = 0$, but without apparently explicitly proving it. Also, I didn't check whether or not $m = 0$ is true or not, including what its specific expression is, as that wasn't asked for here. As you don't show how you got $m = 2 - ts(q^k)$, I'm unsure of how valid that is. If you want to ask about that, I suggest you post a new question specifically about this.

Comment: Okay sure, @JohnOmielan!  Will post a follow-up question in a bit.

Comment: Here is the [new MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4559438), @JohnOmielan.  Thank you for your time and attention!  =)