# On Tony Kuria Kimani's recent preprint in ResearchGate

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

(**Preamble:** The method presented here to compute the GCD $g$ is patterned after the method used to compute a similar GCD in [this answer to a closely related MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4508878/28816).)

Let $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.  Denote the *deficiency* of $x$ by $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$, and the *aliquot sum* of $x$ by $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$.

If $N$ is odd and $\sigma(N)=2N$, then $N$ is called an *odd perfect number*.  Euler proved that an odd perfect number, if one exists, must necessarily have the form
$$N = q^k n^2,$$
where $q$ is the special prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

---

Now, we start with

$$\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)) = \left(q^k t - 2(q - 1)\right)n^2 + \left((-\sigma(q^k)/2)\cdot{t} + q\right)\sigma(n^2),$$

like Tony Kuria Kimani did in [this recent ResearchGate preprint](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/364915201_Notes_on_Odd_perfect_numbers_II).

But
$$\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)) = \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = \frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2} = \frac{s(n^2)}{D(q^k)/2}.$$

Consequently, we have
$$s(n^2) = \sigma(n^2) - n^2 = \left(q^k (D(q^k)/2) t - 2(q - 1)(D(q^k)/2)\right)n^2 + \left((-\sigma(q^k)/2)(D(q^k)/2)\cdot{t} + q(D(q^k)/2)\right)\sigma(n^2).$$

For simpler algebra, let
$$u = q^k (D(q^k)/2) t - 2(q - 1)(D(q^k)/2)$$
and let
$$v = (-\sigma(q^k)/2)(D(q^k)/2)\cdot{t} + q(D(q^k)/2).$$

Then the equation above involving $s(n^2)$ becomes
$$\sigma(n^2) - n^2 = u\cdot{n^2} + v\cdot\sigma(n^2)$$
so that
$$(1-v)\sigma(n^2) = (1+u){n^2}. \tag{1}$$

Dividing both sides of Equation $(1)$ by $\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$, we obtain:
$$(1-v)q^k = (1+u)\cdot(\sigma(q^k)/2). \tag{2}$$
Since $\gcd(q^k,\sigma(q^k)/2)=1$, it follows from Equation $(2)$ that
$$q^k \mid 1+u$$
so that there exists an integer $g$ such that
$$1+u = g\cdot{q^k}. \tag{3}$$
Substituting Equation $(3)$ in Equation $(2)$, we get
$$(1-v)q^k = g\cdot{q^k}\cdot(\sigma(q^k)/2) \implies 1-v=g\cdot(\sigma(q^k)/2). \tag{4}$$
It follows that
$$g=\gcd(1+u,1-v)$$
since $\gcd(q^k,\sigma(q^k)/2)=1$.

Here, we prove that, in fact, $g$ must be odd, and thereby derive an explicit formula for $g$.

Subtracting Equation $(4)$ from Equation $(3)$, we obtain:
$$u+v = g\cdot(D(q^k)/2) = \left(q^k (D(q^k)/2) t - 2(q - 1)(D(q^k)/2)\right) + \left((-\sigma(q^k)/2)(D(q^k)/2)\cdot{t} + q(D(q^k)/2)\right),$$
which implies that
$$g=\gcd(1+u,1-v)=\left(q^k t - 2(q - 1)\right) + \left((-\sigma(q^k)/2)\cdot{t} + q\right)=(D(q^k)/2)\cdot{t} - (q - 2) \equiv 1 \pmod 2,$$
since $D(q^k)/2$ must be even.

---

Here is my:

> **QUESTION:** Is my derivation of the formula
> $$g=\gcd(1+u,1-v)=(D(q^k)/2)\cdot{t} - (q - 2)$$
> correct?

Comment: Contrary to the situation in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4559438/proof-verification-request-on-the-equation-gcdn2-sigman2-dn2-sqk/4559480#comment9591463_4559438), here we know that $t > 0$ always holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer gives an *alternative derivation* for the formula
$$g = \gcd(1+u,1-v) = (D(q^k)/2)\cdot{t} - (q - 2),$$
and thereby attempts to answer the original question.

---

From this [WolframAlpha computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=FullSimplify%5B1%2B%28%28q%5Ek%29%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29+-+2q%5Ek+%2B+1%29%2F%282%28q-1%29%29%29t+-+%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29+-+2q%5Ek+%2B+1%29%5D), we get the following fully simplified expression for $1+u$:

$$1+u = \frac{q^k (tq^{k+1} - 2tq^k - 2q^2 + 6q + t - 4)}{2(q - 1)} = {q^k}\cdot\frac{\left(tq^{k+1} - 2tq^k + t - 2q^2 + 6q - 4\right)}{2(q - 1)}$$
$$= {q^k}\cdot\left(t\cdot\frac{q^{k+1} - 2q^k + 1}{2(q - 1)}-\frac{2(q^2 - 3q + 2)}{2(q - 1)}\right) = {q^k}\cdot\left(t\cdot(D(q^k)/2)-(q-2)\right).$$

Similarly, from this [WolframAlpha computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=FullSimplify%5B1%2B%28%28%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29+-+1%29%2F%282%28q+-+1%29%29%29%28%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29+-+2q%5Ek+%2B+1%29%2F%282%28q-1%29%29%29%29t+-+q%28%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29+-+2q%5Ek+%2B+1%29%2F%282%28q-1%29%29%29%5D), we get the following fully simplified expression for $1-v$:

$$1-v=\frac{(q^{k+1} - 1)(tq^{k+1} - 2tq^k - 2q^2 + 6q + t - 4)}{4(q - 1)^2}$$
$$=\frac{q^{k+1} - 1}{2(q - 1)}\cdot\frac{\left(tq^{k+1} - 2tq^k + t - 2q^2 + 6q - 4\right)}{2(q - 1)}$$
$$=\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}\cdot\left(t\cdot(D(q^k)/2) - (q - 2)\right).$$

Let $g' = t\cdot(D(q^k)/2) - (q - 2)$.

It follows that
$$\gcd(1+u,1-v)=\gcd\left({q^k}\cdot{g'},(\sigma(q^k)/2)\cdot{g'}\right)={g'}\cdot\gcd(q^k,\sigma(q^k)/2)=g'.$$

Note that
$$g=(D(q^k)/2)\cdot{t} - (q - 2)=t\cdot(D(q^k)/2) - (q - 2)=g'.$$

Comment: The approach here is similar to that in this [answer to a closely related MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4559480/28816).