# On the equation $s(n^2) = \left(\frac{q-1}{2}\right)\cdot{D(n^2)}$, if $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Let $N$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) given in the so-called *Eulerian form*
$$N = q^k n^2$$
where $q$ is the *special prime* satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

---

In what follows, let us keep in mind the following lemma:

> **LEMMA:** If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number given in Eulerian form, then $k = 1$ holds if and only if
> $$s(n^2) = \left(\frac{q-1}{2}\right)\cdot{D(n^2)},$$
> where $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$ is the [*aliquot sum*](http://oeis.org/A001065) of the positive integer $x$, $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$ is the [*deficiency*](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $x$, and $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ is the *classical sum of divisors* of $x$.

---

Now, we start with

$$\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)) = \left(q^k t - 2(q - 1)\right)n^2 + \left((-\sigma(q^k)/2)\cdot{t} + q\right)\sigma(n^2),$$

like Tony Kuria Kimani did in [this recent ResearchGate preprint](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/364915201_Notes_on_Odd_perfect_numbers_II).

But the equation
$$\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)) = \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = \frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2} = \frac{s(n^2)}{D(q^k)/2} = \frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}$$
holds.  Consequently, we obtain the simultaneous equations
$$s(n^2) = (D(q^k)/2)\cdot\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$$
$$= \left(q^k (D(q^k)/2) t - 2(q - 1)(D(q^k)/2)\right)n^2 + \left((-\sigma(q^k)/2)(D(q^k)/2)\cdot{t} + q(D(q^k)/2)\right)\sigma(n^2)$$
$$D(n^2) = {s(q^k)}\cdot\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)) = \left(q^k s(q^k) t - 2(q - 1)s(q^k)\right)n^2 + \left((-\sigma(q^k)/2)s(q^k)\cdot{t} + qs(q^k)\right)\sigma(n^2).$$

We now test whether the equation
$$s(n^2) = \left(\frac{q-1}{2}\right)\cdot{D(n^2)}$$
holds; that is, whether the equation
$$\left(q^k (D(q^k)/2) t - 2(q - 1)(D(q^k)/2)\right)n^2 + \left((-\sigma(q^k)/2)(D(q^k)/2)\cdot{t} + q(D(q^k)/2)\right)\sigma(n^2)$$
$$= \left(\frac{q-1}{2}\right)\cdot\Bigg(\left(q^k s(q^k) t - 2(q - 1)s(q^k)\right)n^2 + \left((-\sigma(q^k)/2)s(q^k)\cdot{t} + qs(q^k)\right)\sigma(n^2)\Bigg) \tag{1}$$
is true.

For simpler algebra, let
$$u_1 = q^k (D(q^k)/2) t - 2(q - 1)(D(q^k)/2)$$
$$u_2 = \left(\frac{q-1}{2}\right)\cdot\left(q^k s(q^k) t - 2(q - 1)s(q^k)\right)$$
$$v_1 = (-\sigma(q^k)/2)(D(q^k)/2)\cdot{t} + q(D(q^k)/2)$$
and
$$v_2 = \left(\frac{q-1}{2}\right)\cdot\left((-\sigma(q^k)/2)s(q^k)\cdot{t} + qs(q^k)\right).$$

Then Equation $(1)$ becomes
$$\left(u_1 - u_2\right)\cdot{n^2} = \left(v_2 - v_1\right)\cdot{\sigma(n^2)}. \tag{2}$$

We now attempt to get simplified expressions for [$u_1 - u_2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=FullSimplify%5Bq%5Ek+%28%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29+-+2q%5Ek+%2B+1%29%2F%282%28q+-+1%29%29%29+t+-+%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29+-+2q%5Ek+%2B+1%29+-+%28q%5Ek+%28%28q%5Ek+-+1%29%2F2%29+t+-+%28q+-+1%29%28q%5Ek+-+1%29%29%5D) and [$v_2 - v_1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=FullSimplify%5B%28%28%28q%5Ek+-+1%29%28q%28-tq%5Ek+%2B+2q+-+2%29+%2B+t%29%29%2F%284%28q+-+1%29%29%29+%2B+%28%28%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29+-+2q%5Ek+%2B+1%29%28t%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29+-+1%29+-+2q%5E2+%2B+2q%29%29%2F%284%28q+-+1%29%5E2%29%29%5D) using WolframAlpha.  We obtain the following:
$$u_1 - u_2 = -\left(\frac{q^k - q}{2(q - 1)}\right)\cdot\left(tq^k - 2q + 2\right)$$
$$v_2 - v_1 = -\left(\frac{q^k - q}{2(q - 1)}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{q(tq^k - 2q + 2) - t}{2(q - 1)}\right). \tag{3}$$

Dividing both sides of Equation $(2)$ by $d = \gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$, we obtain
$$\left(u_1 - u_2\right)\cdot\Bigg({\frac{n^2}{d}}\Bigg) = \left(v_2 - v_1\right)\cdot\Bigg(\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{d}\Bigg).$$
Recall that
$$d = \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = \frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2}.$$
Consequently, we have
$$\left(u_1 - u_2\right)\cdot\Bigg(\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}\Bigg) = \left(v_2 - v_1\right)\cdot{q^k}. \tag{4}$$

Since $\gcd(q^k,\sigma(q^k)/2)=1$, then there exists an integer $G$ such that
$$v_2 - v_1 = G\cdot\left(\sigma(q^k)/2\right).$$
Substituting into Equation $(4)$, we get
$$\left(u_1 - u_2\right)\cdot\Bigg(\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}\Bigg) = G\cdot\left(\sigma(q^k)/2\right)\cdot{q^k},$$
from which we finally obtain
$$u_1 - u_2 = G\cdot{q^k}.$$

We therefore finally get
$$\gcd(u_1 - u_2, v_2 - v_1) = \gcd\Bigg(G\cdot{q^k}, G\cdot\left(\sigma(q^k)/2\right)\Bigg) = G\cdot\gcd(q^k, \sigma(q^k)/2) = G. \tag{5}$$

---

To recap, we have obtained
$$G = \gcd(u_1 - u_2, v_2 - v_1).$$

However, from the equations in $(3)$, we also get
$$\gcd(u_1 - u_2, v_2 - v_1) = -\left(\frac{q^k - q}{2(q - 1)}\right).$$

Hence, we finally have
$$G = \gcd(u_1 - u_2, v_2 - v_1) = -\left(\frac{q^k - q}{2(q - 1)}\right).$$

Since GCDs are always nonnegative, then $G \geq 0$, which means that we have
$$q^k - q \leq 0.$$
This implies that $k \leq 1$.  Since $k \geq 1$ ought to hold (because $k$ is a positive integer satisfying $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$), then we now know that $k=1$.

Quite apparently, this implies that $G = 0$, whereupon we obtain $u_1 = u_2$ and $v_1 = v_2$.

---

Here is my question:

> Can I define GCDs to be *always positive* (so that $G > 0$ in the previous section) and thereby get a proof for $k \neq 1$?

Comment: The method for obtaining $G$ here is patterned after those in [answer link 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4559480/28816) and [answer link 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4565473/28816).

Comment: You may assume that $G>0$, but then this should be taken into account, and in the last expression for $G$, the minus sign should be removed.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, Professor Dujella @duje!   So when $G > 0$, then $G \geq 1$, so that I get
$$G = \frac{q^k - q}{2(q - 1)} \geq 1,$$
from which we obtain
$$q^k \geq 3q - 2,$$
which **does not force** a contradiction.  =(

Comment: It does prove, however, that $q = 5$ and $k = 1$ is **untenable**.

Comment: Blimey!  How could I have missed it, Professor Dujella, @duje?

$$q^k \geq 3q - 2 \implies q^k - 1 \geq 3q - 3 = 3(q - 1) \implies s(q^k) = \frac{q^k - 1}{q - 1} \geq 3,$$

which contradicts $k = 1$, since this latter assumption implies $s(q^k) = 1$.

Hence, $k \neq 1$ holds!

Comment: If you want to conclude something for $k=1$, then you should insert it in your computations from the beginning. Otherwise, you might multiply and divide by $0$ (i.e. $q^1-q$).

Comment: Okay, Professor Dujella, @duje!  So here I go:  Assume to the contrary that $k=1$.  Then
$$G = \frac{q^k - q}{2(q - 1)} = \frac{q^1 - q}{2(q - 1)} = 0,$$
which contradicts $G \geq 1$.

Comment: Basically, my approach here (as well as in my two newest answers) has been to use GCD theory to derive conclusions about the truth or falsity of $k=1$.  (Note that nowhere did I use division by $G$ in the original post, and that I know that $d = \gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)) \geq 3$.) @duje

Comment: It seems that for $k=1$, you have $G=\gcd(0,0)$, and I do not see how you can conclude anything from here.

Comment: Yes, $k = 1$ implies $G = \gcd(0,0) = 0$, Professor Dujella, @duje.  Which is why I wanted to see if I could assume that GCDs are **always positive**, in general, in order to conclude $k \neq 1$.

Comment: By the usual definition, $\gcd(a.b)$ is positive if at least one of $a$ and $b$ is nonzero. If you take the convention that $\gcd(0,0)=0$, then, of course, GCD can be $0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140378/discussion-between-duje-and-arnie-bebita-dris).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this self-answer, thanks to hints from [Professor Dujella](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82393) in the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140378/discussion-between-duje-and-arnie-bebita-dris).

---

First, we show that the assumption $G > 0$ leads to a contradiction.

It is clear that, under the assumption $G > 0$, $k \neq 1$ holds.  (This is because $k = 1$ implies that $G = 0$.)

Then I obtain (from Equation $(4)$ in the original post) that
$$I(q^k) = \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{q^k} = \frac{2(v_2 - v_1)}{u_1 - u_2} = \frac{q(tq^k - 2q + 2) - t}{(q - 1)(tq^k - 2q + 2)} = \frac{q}{q - 1} - \frac{t}{(q - 1)(tq^k - 2q + 2)}. \tag{1}$$

(Note that from Equation $(1)$ in this answer, we have $t \neq 0$.)

We obtain
$$\frac{1}{q^k (q - 1)} = \frac{t}{(q - 1)(tq^k - 2q + 2)}$$
which is equivalent to
$$0 = \left(\frac{1}{q - 1}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{q^k} - \frac{t}{tq^k - 2q + 2}\right) = \left(\frac{1}{q - 1}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{tq^k - 2q + 2 - tq^k}{tq^k - 2q + 2}\right) = -\frac{2(q - 1)}{(q - 1)(tq^k - 2q + 2)}.$$
Now, since *a priori* we know that $q \geq 5$ holds, then we may cancel $q - 1$ from both numerator and denominator of the last fraction, to get
$$0 = -\frac{2}{tq^k - 2q + 2},$$
resulting in the contradiction
$$0 = -2.$$

(Note that $tq^k - 2q + 2 \neq 0$, because otherwise we would get
$$t = \frac{2(q - 1)}{q^k},$$
which implies that $q^k \mid 2(q - 1)$ (since $t$ must be an integer), contradicting $\gcd(2,q)=\gcd(q-1,q)=1$.)

Hence, we conclude that $G = 0$ must hold.

---

Now, we claim that:

> **CLAIM:** $G = 0$ if and only if $k = 1$.

*Proof:* The implication $k = 1 \implies G = 0$ is obvious.

For the converse, assume that $G = 0$.

Then we obtain the system of equations
$$0 = u_1 - u_2 = - \left(\frac{q^k - q}{2(q - 1)}\right)\cdot(tq^k - 2q + 2) \tag{2}$$
$$0 = v_2 - v_1 = - \left(\frac{q^k - q}{2(q - 1)}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{q(tq^k - 2q + 2) - t}{2(q - 1)}\right). \tag{3}$$

Now, note that (referencing Equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ in this answer), we have
$$(2) \iff \left((q^k - q = 0) \lor (tq^k - 2q + 2 = 0)\right) \land (q \neq 1) \iff k = 1,$$
since $tq^k - 2q + 2 = 0$ contradicts the requirement that $t$ must be an integer.
$$(3) \iff \left((q^k - q = 0) \lor (q(tq^k - 2q + 2) - t = 0)\right) \land (q \neq 1) \iff \left((k = 1) \lor (t(q^{k+1} - 1) = 2q(q - 1))\right) \land (q \neq 1) \iff \Bigg((k = 1) \lor \left(1 < t = \frac{2q}{\sigma(q^k)} = \frac{2q}{q + 1} < 2\right)\Bigg) \land (q \neq 1) \iff k = 1,$$
which completes the proof.