# Proof-verification request: On the equation $\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=D(n^2)/s(q^k)$ - Part II

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

(**Preamble:** This inquiry is an offshoot of this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4508878/28816) to a closely related question.)

In what follows, denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$, the *deficiency* of $x$ by $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$, and the *aliquot sum* of $x$ by $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$.

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.  Descartes, Frenicle, and subsequently Sorli conjectured that $k=1$ always holds.  (In this **proof-verification** request, we shall attempt to show sufficient conditions to prove this conjecture.)

Using the fundamental equation
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)=\sigma(q^k n^2)=\sigma(N)=2N=2q^k n^2$$
and using the fact that $q^k$ and $\sigma(q^k)$ are *relatively prime* (that is, $\gcd(q^k,\sigma(q^k))=1$), then we get that $q^k \mid \sigma(n^2)$, whereupon we obtain that
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}$$
is an odd integer.

We then obtain the **identities**
$$\gcd\bigl(n^2,\sigma(n^2)\bigr)=\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}=\frac{2s(n^2)}{D(q^k)}.$$

Now, in a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4506498/are-the-bezout-coefficients-for-gcdn2-sigman2-q-sigman2-2q#comment9464753_4508176) underneath [MSE user Aravind](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/4959)'s answer to a related MSE question, we derived that
$$\gcd\bigl(n^2,\sigma(n^2)\bigr)=n^2 \bigl(q^k t - 2(q - 1)\bigr) + \sigma(n^2) \bigl( - (\sigma(q^k)/2)\cdot t + q \bigr), \tag{1}$$
where $t$ is necessarily an **integer** to be determined by using the identity
$$\gcd\bigl(n^2,\sigma(n^2)\bigr)=\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}. \tag{2}$$

Equating $(1)$ and $(2)$, we obtain
$$\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}=n^2 \bigl(q^k t - 2(q - 1)\bigr) + \sigma(n^2) \bigl( - (\sigma(q^k)/2)\cdot t + q \bigr). \tag{3}$$
Multiplying both sides of $(3)$ by $s(q^k)$, we obtain
$$2n^2 - \sigma(n^2) = D(n^2) = n^2 \bigl(q^k s(q^k) t - 2(q - 1)s(q^k)\bigr) + \sigma(n^2) \bigl( - (\sigma(q^k)/2) s(q^k) \cdot t + q s(q^k) \bigr). \tag{4}$$

Equating coefficients for $n^2$ and $\sigma(n^2)$ in $(4)$, we have that
$$\begin{cases}
2  = q^k s(q^k) t - 2(q - 1)s(q^k) \\
-1 = - (\sigma(q^k)/2) s(q^k) \cdot t + q s(q^k) 
\end{cases} \tag{5}
$$

For simpler algebra, let

$$u = q^k s(q^k) t - 2(q - 1)s(q^k), \; \; v = -(\sigma(q^k)/2)s(q^k) \cdot t + q s(q^k) \tag{6}\label{eq1A}$$

then $(4)$ becomes

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
2n^2 - \sigma(n^2) & = u \cdot n^2 + v \cdot \sigma(n^2) \\
(2 - u)n^2 & = (1 + v)\sigma(n^2)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{7}\label{eq2A}$$

From $(2)$, we have

$$\gcd\bigl(n^2,\sigma(n^2)\bigr)=\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)} = d \; \; \to \; \; \gcd\left(\frac{n^2}{d},\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{d}\right) = 1 \tag{8}\label{eq3A}$$

Dividing both sides of \eqref{eq2A} by $d$ gives

$$(2 - u)\left(\frac{n^2}{d}\right) = (1 + v)\left(\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{d}\right) \tag{9}\label{eq4A}$$

Due to the right side $\gcd$ condition in \eqref{eq3A}, we next have

$$\frac{n^2}{d} \mid (1 + v) \; \; \to \; \; 1 + v = m\left(\frac{n^2}{d}\right) \tag{10}\label{eq5A}$$

for some integer $m$. Substituting this into \eqref{eq4A} and dividing both sides by $\frac{n^2}{d}$ gives

$$2 - u = m\left(\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{d}\right) \tag{11}\label{eq6A}$$

---

So to recap, essentially we have shown that
$$\gcd(1+v,2-u)=m \tag{12}$$
where $u$ and $v$ are defined in \eqref{eq1A}.

We now claim that $m = 2 - ts(q^k)$.  (Note that having $m = 0$ is equivalent to the method of equating coefficients as in $(5)$.)

We have
$$1+v = 1 - (\sigma(q^k)/2)s(q^k)t + qs(q^k) = m\cdot\Bigg(\frac{n^2}{d}\Bigg)=m\cdot\Bigg(\frac{n^2}{\frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2}}\Bigg)=m\cdot(\sigma(q^k)/2) \tag{13}$$
and
$$2-u = 2 - q^k s(q^k) t + 2(q - 1)s(q^k) = m\cdot\Bigg(\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{d}\Bigg)=m\cdot\Bigg(\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{\sigma(n^2)/q^k}\Bigg)=m\cdot q^k. \tag{14}$$

Multiply Equation $(13)$ by $2$, then subtract Equation $(14)$, to get
$$2(1+v) - (2-u) = 2v + u = -\sigma(q^k)s(q^k)t + 2qs(q^k) + q^k s(q^k) t - 2(q - 1)s(q^k) = m\cdot{s(q^k)}. \tag{15}$$

Divide Equation $(15)$ by $s(q^k) \geq 1$, which then gives
$$-\sigma(q^k)t + 2q + q^k t - 2(q - 1) = m = 2 - ts(q^k).$$

**QED**

---

Using the equation $m = 2 - ts(q^k)$, one can show that the following implications hold:

> $m = 0 \implies k = 1$ - The truth of this implication is shown in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4508811/28816).

> $m = 1 \implies k = 1$ - Proof: Let $m = 1$, and assume to the contrary that $k \neq 1$.  Then $k \geq 5$ (since $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ holds).  But
> $$s(q^k) = \sigma(q^k) - q^k = 1 + q + \ldots + q^{k-1} = \frac{q^k - 1}{q - 1}$$
> $$\frac{\partial}{\partial k} s(q^k) = \frac{q^k \ln q}{q - 1} > 0$$
> so that $s(q^k)$ is an increasing function of $k$ (for $q \geq 5$ and $k \geq 5$).  In particular,
> $$s(q^k) = \frac{q^k - 1}{q - 1} \geq s(q^5) = \frac{q^5 - 1}{q - 1} \geq \frac{5^5 - 1}{5 - 1} = 781.$$
> Hence, we have
> $$1 = 2 - m = ts(q^k) \geq 781t,$$
> which contradicts the fact that $t$ must be an integer, since $t > 0$ follows from $1 = ts(q^k)$ and $s(q^k) > 1$.

---

Here then, are our questions:

> **QUESTION #1:** Is our proof for $m = 2 - ts(q^k)$ logically correct?  If not, how can it be mended so as to produce a valid argument?

> **QUESTION #2:** Are our proofs for the implications $m = 0 \implies k = 1$ and $m = 1 \implies k = 1$ logically correct?  If possible, can they be extended to a full proof for the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture that $k=1$?

Comment: We noted that $t$ could be negative.  We also noticed that if we could show that $t > 0$ always holds, then this would prove that $k=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative proof for $m=2-ts(q^k)$, and therefore attempts to answer **QUESTION #1**.

---

We compute the fully simplified expressions for [$1+v$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=FullSimplify%5B1-%28%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29+-+1%29%28q%5Ek+-+1%29%2F%282%28q-1%29%5E2%29%29t%2Bq%28%28q%5Ek+-+1%29%2F%28q-1%29%29%5D) and [$2-u$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=FullSimplify%5B2-%28%28q%5Ek+-+1%29%2F%28q-1%29%29%28q%5Ek%29t%2B2%28q-1%29%28%28q%5Ek+-+1%29%2F%28q-1%29%29%5D) using WolframAlpha, and we obtain
$$1+v=-\frac{(q^{k+1} - 1)(tq^k - 2q - t + 2)}{2(q-1)^2}$$
and
$$2-u=-\frac{q^k (tq^k - 2q - t + 2)}{q - 1}$$
so that
$$m=\gcd(1+v,2-u)=-\Bigg(\frac{tq^k - 2q - t + 2}{q - 1}\Bigg)$$
since $\gcd(q^{k+1} - 1, q^k)=1$.
But
$$m=-\Bigg(\frac{tq^k - 2q - t + 2}{q - 1}\Bigg)=2-t\Bigg(\frac{q^k - 1}{q - 1}\Bigg)=2-ts(q^k),$$
an equation which we know holds.